# Cython beginner - speed up numpy broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

Trying Cython for the first time, trying to get a speedup on a function that does subtraction and addition on 2 numpy arrays and a float32. I'm trying to get this function to be as quick as possible it's called a lot of times and if i can speed this up then it's a big win.

```
 def broadcast(w, m, spl):
       """
       w and m are float32 ndarrays e.g shape (43,)
       spl is an nd.float32 value e.g 9722.0
       """
        return w + (m - spl)
```

My cythonising so far is

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

def broadcast(np.ndarray w, np.ndarray m, np.float32 spl):
    return w + (m - spl)
```

but it returns the error:

```
'float32' is not a type identifier
```

I'm not sure how why I can't declare the type? Do I need to declare a C type? What is an np.float32 in C?

Comment: You need ``np.float32_t`` instead of ``np.float32``

Comment: why not `DTYPE_t spl`?

Comment: I don't think Cython will help with this. Cython can't optimize the addition and subtraction, which will be handled by Numpy internals, and you aren't trying to access individual elements or write explicit loops. You might want to check out [Numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) which can optimize away the intermediate arrays that are normally created when you evaluate `w + (m - spl)` and similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by @YXD, you won't get a speed improvement using Cython to loop over the arrays to perform these operations. Specially for simple operations, Numpy uses SIMD programming which is very efficient.

Despite of that, you could improve the memory usage and the performance by modifying array `w` in place, **if the original array is no longer needed**:

```
def func(w, m, spl)
    w += m
    w -= spl
```

then, instead of calling:

```
out = func(w, m, spl)
```

the new call:

```
func(w, m, spl)
```

will store the output inside `w`.